# Timezone in database not according to timezone set in settings.py Django

Tags: sqlite, datetime, django-models, timezone

I am currently working on a django project in which i wanna add the create_at and updated_at fields in django models i have done with that part using `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` set both true, and time is perfectly saving in my sqlite database.
But the problem comes when i retrive the time from database it shows me time correctly but not according to my local time zone. even though i have set in my settings.py like that

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Karachi'
```

but i want to keep consistancy in my view and my database. for now to get according local time zone  what tried is:

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> timezone.now()
datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 4, 7, 35, 4, 879169, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> timezone.localtime()
datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 4, 12, 38, 39, 129903, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Asia/Karachi'))
>>> from customAuth.models import OTP
>>> record = OTP.objects.first()
>>> record
<OTP: trydifferentwaysforpractice@gmail.com>
>>> timestored = record.timeout
>>> timestored
datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 3, 17, 14, 28, 51644, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> timezone.localtime(timestored)
datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 3, 22, 14, 28, 51644, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Asia/Karachi'))
>>> timezone.localtime(timestored.time()) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Django-Learn-Math\DjangoLearnMathProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\timezone.py", line 183, in localtime
    raise ValueError("localtime() cannot be applied to a naive datetime")
ValueError: localtime() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
>>> converted = timezone.localtime(timestored)
>>> converted
datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 3, 22, 14, 28, 51644, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Asia/Karachi'))
>>> converted.time()
DateTime.time(22, 14, 28, 51644)
>>>
```

[image: Python shell time conversion to local time zone]

here is snippet from my database
[image: database record picture]

now guide me on how I can keep consistency between view and database record to store time according to local time zone

Answer (score 1):

This is the right behavior in Django, all times are stored in UTC and if you set the timezone in the settings file, Django will show the time in the timezone automatically to the users. This mechanism is correct so the SaaS applications can serve users in different timezones or when the user jumps between zones.

For more information, check [Django Help](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/timezones/)